# FullPage JS onLeave

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using [FullPage JS](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) to build a site.

I want to change the css of a class **as I move** to the next section (not `afterLoad`). I'm trying to do this using the parameters `index` and `nextIndex` in the `onLeave` function.

Basically what I'm looking for

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex){
    // leaving index - add color overlay
    $(".dark").css("background-color","rgba(0,0,0,.55)");

    // entering nextIndex - remove color overlay
    $(".dark").css("background-color","rgba(0,0,0,0)");
}
```

All help appreciated! Cheers.

HTML:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section0"><div class="dark"></div><h1>fullPage.js</h1></div>
    <div class="section" id="section1"><div class="dark"></div><h1 style="color: #000;">hello</h1></div>
    <div class="section" id="section2"><div class="dark"></div><h1>Lovely images <br />for a lovely page</h1></div>
    <div class="section" id="section3"><div class="dark"></div><h1>One Image = One thousand words</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what errors do you encounter ?

Comment: Hi John, I'm not great with JS - I just can't seem to find the syntax to say in `nextIndex` change `dark`, or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** based on your HTML markup.

The `index` and `nextIndex` are based on the child elements of the element on which FullPage is instantiated on.

So this should work:

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex){
    // leaving index - add color overlay
    $(".section").eq(index-1).find(".dark").css("background-color","rgba(0,0,0,.55)");

    // entering nextIndex - remove color overlay
    $(".section").eq(nextIndex-1).find(".dark").css("background-color","rgba(0,0,0,0)");
}
```

Comment: It should be `$(".section").eq(index-1) and `.eq(nextIndex-1)` as the index parameters [in fullPage.js are not 0 based but 1 based](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction), unlike in Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: @Alvaro: Wow... Thanks for this important detail!